# Different variables repeated ANOVA

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, methodology

Is conducting repeated measures ANOVA appropriate on two different variables collected from the same subject (e.g. rated difficulty and response time)? So, there is no treatment, just a couple of measures collected from each participant.

I've never seen such practice, and am pretty confused as whether I should refuse to conduct this analysis. Is it anyhow statistically grounded? If not what are the analyses I should use to compare these measures (I'm guessing regression, but just to be sure).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand, you have two dependent variables. Do you have any independent variables? WIth multiple dependent variables you can do a MANOVA but you must have at least one IV.

Comment: Yes there are some IVs - such as multiple demographics, one for type of task assigned to subject, and one for his native language. I'm aware of MANOVA, but as I'm not analyzing my data but someone else's I just wanted to know whether his request (that I've described above) can be methodologically sound?

Answer (score 0):

No, this doesn't make sense either conceptually or statistically. You've not explained what you research question is but I cannot image a meaningful research question that would treat these as a repeated measure. Doing so is testing whether the mean of the one variable equals the mean of the other (i.e., time 1 is different from time 2). If the measures are different, this is a meaningless test. I would recommend two separate models, a MANVOA type model, or SUREG (semmingly unrelated regression).